# Did I forget how to set up an initial state in React? (React native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So consider the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

class CreateTweet extends Component {

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      text: 'Fake Value'
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 100,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('CreateTweet', () => CreateTweet);

module.exports = CreateTweet;
```

When run the state is `null`. You can see the `console.log(this.state)` I am setting the state when the component is initialized, What is going on? Is there some magic I don't know about in React native thats different then React?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using classes, your state should be set up in a constructor:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
      text: 'Fake Value'
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you can still use `React.createClass` if you prefer that way!

Comment: This is what I thought I was missing >.> Thank you